# How to prevent ad blockers killing links in Google Apps Script custom dialogs that use google.script.host.close()

Tags: google-apps-script

In the [documentation for custom dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs) it suggests  calling `google.script.host.close()` to close the window. I'm using this as part of a flow that requires the user to open a new browser tab from the dialog e.g.

```
<a href="<?= SERVICE_URL ?>" onclick="google.script.host.close();" class="button action" target="_blank" id="next-button">Easy Setup</a>
```

This works for most people, the dialog window closes and the user opens a new tab, but I finding some users are seeing adblockers killing the link meaning the dialog doesn't close and more worryingly the new tab isn't opened.

I could just remove the onclick on the `<a>` but wondered if there was a better solution that would still close the dialog when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd move the code to a function.  You can open another browser tab with the DOM instead of an `<a>` tag.

```
<button class="action" onmouseup="openAnotherTab()">Easy Setup</button>

window.openAnotherTab= function() {
  window.open(href="url", target="_blank");
  google.script.host.close();
};
```

I haven't tested this with ad blockers, but I'd think that the ad blocker is looking at HTML Elements and not script tags.

Comment: Struggling to replicate reported issue so can't confirm it works with ad blockers but certainly fixed reported issue with FF